# Radially magnetize a ring magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I need to radially magnetize a ring made of a magnetic alloy. Do I need two solenoids to do this? If yes, one should be inside as a cathode and the other outside as the anode? Practically, which solenoid should be attached to the positive pole to make north facing center? Can I use a $12V$ volt battery to do this?

The measures of the ring magnet are the following:

Outer Diameter $180mm$ Inner Diameter $140mm$ Height $25mm$ Thickness $20mm$.

Answer (score 0):

The aim is to make magnetic Fields pass radially outward in the ring. This can be done if you put several small magnets inside the ring, facing outwards.

You can also use coil to produce the same effect. The key would be to fill the entire outer or inner face of the ring with electric coil to produce significant magnetic fields.

Comment: If I choose the second option, i should use only one coil, where do i have to put it to make north facing center, inside the ring or outside? Do you think 12V is enough to produce a significant magnetic field? Does it matter the time of exposition to the magnetic field?

Comment: From outside, if you give clock-wise current, the center should become north facing. You can do the same on the inner part of the ring as well. I am not sure whether 12 volt will be sufficient or not. The time of exposition surely matters but there is an upper limit after which the effect becomes negligible. I would suggest giving a current supply for five to ten seconds at a time. You can then observe the progress.

Answer (score 0):

A solenoid, with N pole distant from the S pole, is a poor geometry
to accomplish this magnetization.

You will  need a N pole inside the ring, a S pole outside the ring... and
it may take a very strong magnet.   If the ring can be heated to the Curie temperature as the field is applied, it will be magnetized easily as it cools.

There is no obvious purpose for such a magnet structure, though it could be
fitted with a central pin and an outer collar, and serve as a speaker
magnet (usually, though, the central pin has enough volume to put the
magnet there).

Comment: @Whit3d Is this a correct setting? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/imgmag/tor.gif  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @RobertFalco The gif shows mainly poloidal current around a torus; that will generate NO external field, no N or S poles, unless you cut the torus into two horseshoe magnets later... to induce radial poles, takes a cup magnet with a center pin; the end of the center pin being N, and the magnetic field return path going through the cup to the distant S pole of the center pin.  The cup bottom will be polarized with its N  pole against the S pole of the center pin, and S pole at the perimeter, so is an inverse-oriented ring magnet to the target.